# Get item selected from NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

I am using collection view to display remote directory. Unlike table view which has `selectionDidChange` deleagates, this doesnt have any. I checked a lot of questions here, and tried to use the solutions.

Since its a directory that will be displayed, each item would have different action based on the type of file. If its a directory sub folders would be fetched and if its a file it would display the file details in other view. Am using `observeValueForKeyPath` method to listen to clicks on collection view items.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"selectionIndexes"] && [[arrayController selectedObjects] count]) {
        int idx = [arrayController selectionIndex];
        MyFileModel *selectedFile = [myFilesArray objectAtIndex:idx];
        if ([selectedFile.fileType isEqualToString:@"dir"]){
            [self fetchSubFoldersForDir:selectedFile];
        } else {
            [self fetchFileDetailsForFile:selectedFile];
        }
    }
}
```

Observer is added in awake from nib. Now the problem is that by default 0th index is always selected. So it will automatically trigger if else blocks for the first file always. So if I have a folder structure like `a->b->c` by default I would be seeing the contents of C directory always.

Is there any other way to do this other using observers ?

Comment: Why don't you use IKImageBrowser?

Comment: @BlueTomato I have not used it previously, but looking at [the reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html) even it doesnt support table view kind of delegates. So I think we need to use a similar observer to get clicked item information. But I would be stuck in same situation all over again.